# PHP - Laravel : How to save without time overlapping in DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have a situation where user will save time interval in database means schedule where it won't effect others time.

> Eg: If a classroom is already booked for 7:00Am to 8:00am user can't
>   save time in between that time means user can't save 7:30 to 8:30 or
>   in that time interval.

How do I check the time interval and save the time it in laravel?

Here is my controller:

```
 public function postAllocateRoom(Request $request)
    {

            $classRoom = new ClassRoom();           
            $classRoom->department_id=$request->Input(['department_id']);     
            $classRoom->room_id=$request->Input(['room_id']); 
            $classRoom->course_id=$request->Input(['course_id']); 
            $classRoom->day_id=$request->Input(['day_id']); 
            $classRoom->start=$request->Input(['start']); 
            $classRoom->end=$request->Input(['end']);        
            $classRoom->save();            
            return redirect('allocateRoomPage'); 
    }
```

I have `two` columns in my db with the name of `start` and `end` type: `Time`

Comment: You should use Javascript or jQuery for this functionality. Just hide specific time which is used from dropdown in view.

Comment: can you suggest me One. I searched but couldn't find helpful any.

Answer (score 2):

If you want check it in server side you should make additional request to DB for checking time.

```
$startTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('start'));
$endTime = Carbon::parse($request->input('end'));

$classRoomCount = ClassRoom::where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('start', '>=', $startTime)
          ->where('end', '<=', $startTime);
})->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query->where('start', '>=', $endTime)
          ->where('end', '<=', $endTime);
})->count();

if ($classRoomCount > 0) {
    echo 'Classroom is already booked';
}
```

Comment: I should check with the time not date. And yes I want to check with the already save database!

Comment: What format do you use for storing start and end time?

Comment: Just try check start and end point with already saved data in database. See example.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the interval is taken when saving, and as an addition, you could also extract the existing intervals beforehand to present them client-side.